# How to config KIGG to run properly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm very new for ASP.NET MVC. I found that this is very cool thing and KIGG is good to start creating real MVC web application.

I've followed KIGG development guide part 1 and run application.

However, only listing directory shows on web browser as below

Directory Listing -- /

```
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> ActionResult
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> App_Data
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> Assets
Friday, February 05, 2010 01:08 PM        <dir> bin
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> BootstrapperTasks
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> Controllers
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> Controls
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> DataServices
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> ErrorPages
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> Extension
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> Filters
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> Handlers
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> Helpers
Monday, February 15, 2010 08:33 AM        <dir> Logs
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> MailTemplates
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> Modules
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:45 PM        <dir> obj
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> Properties
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> ViewData
Friday, February 05, 2010 12:44 PM        <dir> Views
  Sunday, August 16, 2009 12:53 PM          103 Global.asax
  Sunday, August 16, 2009 12:53 PM          601 Global.asax.cs
  Sunday, August 16, 2009 12:53 PM       27,779 Kigg.Web.csproj
Friday, February 05, 2010 01:35 PM        1,532 Kigg.Web.csproj.user
  Sunday, August 16, 2009 12:53 PM          170 robots.txt
Monday, February 15, 2010 08:54 AM      100,524 Web.config
```

Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 9.0.0.0

Please could you help me to solver my problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following address in your browser: `http://localhost:PORT/story/published` where `PORT` is the port number assigned by Visual Studio's web development server.